# Stagefright media delay in 2.2 after setting data source?

Tags: android, service, media, android-2.2-froyo

My first post here. This website has been very useful for learning Android programming, thanks to everyone.

I have a simple app that loads an MP3 stream and plays it. It works fine on 1.6 and 2.1 but on 2.2 it doesn't quite work right. It seems my service is having a problem starting, it's giving my an ANR and the dialog where I have to tap "Wait", and then finally the service starts. Why is the service taking a long time to start up?

Here's my simple code that sets the source and plays the audio:

```
    public class MyActivityService extends Service {

 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;
 }
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {  
  super.onCreate();   

  try {

   player.setDataSource("URL OF MUSIC FILE");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {

   player.prepare();
   player.setVolume(1, 1);
      player.setLooping(true);           
      player.start();                   

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Service Started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

**ADDENDUM:**

Turns out it wasn't my service not starting, it's the audio that's not starting quickly enough in 2.2...

I got rid of the ANRs when my service started and stopped by putting the `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods of my service in their own threads, which is probably how it should have been from the beginning? Sorry, just learning.

But the delay that's the real problem remains, to clarify --

For example, my code, as it is right now, works fine and dandy and just how I want it to in 2.1 AND 2.2 when I set the data source to an MP3 file like this: **http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6916184/TestSongStream.mp3**

BUT when I set the data source to an audio stream location like this: **http://d.liveatc.net/kjfk_twr** or this: **http://relay.radioreference.com:80/192236577** it works correctly ONLY in 2.1.

In 2.2 the sound does start playing eventually, but it takes "StagefrightPlayer" about 25 seconds or so after setting the data source until the audio starts as shown here:

```
07-31 02:54:30.176: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('http://relay.radioreference.com:80/192236577')
07-31 02:54:55.228: INFO/AwesomePlayer(34): calling prefetcher->prepare()
07-31 02:54:56.231: INFO/Prefetcher(34): [0x2cc28] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
07-31 02:54:56.337: INFO/AwesomePlayer(34): prefetcher is done preparing
07-31 02:54:56.347: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
07-31 02:54:57.337: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(34): Not sending buffering status because duration is unknown.
```

It also takes the same amount of time, about 25 seconds, to stop the media player after `player.stop()` is called in the `onDestroy()` method of my service, and the `onDestroy()` method continues on to Toast a message and cancel a notification.

Is that just the way it is with 2.2? If so, I can work around the delays, that's not a problem. Or more likely is it something I am doing wrong? But it works exactly as I want in 1.6 and 2.1!

Would posting more code help?

My code is very simple. There are no audio controls or anything like that. Simply a start audio button and stop audio button that start and stop a service that plays an audio stream.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered that this problem has something to do with the particular audio stream I am trying to play. I tried different streams ans it played fine. What type of audio stream would play fine in 1.6 and 2.1 but not in 2.2? I know it's because in 2.2 the media framework is all different. I still need to be able to play the stream that isn't working without the service timing out! What should I try? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please ignore my update comment above and see the Addendum in my original question I think I clarified the real issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm hitting the same thing in my app, @ShadowGod were you able to come up with any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `prepare()` from the main application thread, particularly for a stream, because that may take much longer than you're allowed before an ANR. Use `prepareAsync()` instead. I have no idea if that is the root of your particular problem, but it would certainly be one cause of an ANR in your current implementation.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the ANRs can you see my addendum above? Any thoughts?

Comment: @ShadowGod: sorry, but I have no more ideas regarding your issue.